# passing string from controller to view

Tags: javascript, ajax

This JavaScript code is being used to pass a string from a view to an action in a controller:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/brandsOfACategory',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset:utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(this.id)
        })
    });
</script>
```

`brandsOfACategory` code in the controller:

```
public ActionResult brandsOfACategory(string id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Code is not working as expected as `id` is coming as null.

Can someone please guide?

Comment: You say `brandOfACategory` is not being invoked. Do you mean `brandsOfACategory` (plural)? @Jeto the context of `this` here is the callback itself, so I do not think that is the issue.

Comment: @ram1 Oops, you're right, let me retract that.

Comment: I mean `brandOfACategory ` action in the controller is not being invoked .. no plural.. it is just one action in the controller of its name.

Comment: Then it appears you should change the value in line 5 from `/brandsOfACategory` to `/brandOfACategory`.

Answer (score 0):

The code logic and syntax look fine. To test:

1. On this page, run the code in your JS console.
2. Open the network tab.
3. Open one of the links on this page in a new tab.
4. The network request has a pending status.
5. Dismiss the alert.
6. The network request fires.

Steps 4 and 5 go away if you remove the alert.